# Sort Strings in java

Tags: java, string, sorting, guava

I have a `List<Bean>` in which I have object value which is `String`. These strings look like this "This is 1", "This is 10", "This is 2", "This is 11"
My question is how to sort them using guava to be in the order 1, 2, 10, 11?

```
List<Bean> orderedList = new ArrayList<>();
    Function<Bean, String> getNameFunction = new Function<Bean, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(Bean from) {
            return from.getShape();
        }
    };
    Ordering<Bean> nameOrdering = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(getNameFunction);
    ImmutableSortedSet<Bean> sortedShapes = ImmutableSortedSet.orderedBy(
            nameOrdering).addAll(lb).build();
    orderedList.addAll(sortedShapes);
    return orderedList;
```

This is not working like I want it sorts them like 1, 10, 11, 2
Can you please help me?
Thank you!

Comment: I don't know much about Guava, but read up on writing your own `Comparator` implementation. That is the standard way to do this so that a sort will work how you expect it to.

Comment: aren't you trying to order strings instead of numbers?

Comment: the order 1, 10, 11, 2 seems correct to me. You're ordering Strings.

Comment: I don't think that whether you are using Guava makes any difference regarding your actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default (natural) ordering for `Java` `Strings` is [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), which means `Strings` are ordered alphabetically of their *component letters* (character by character comparison). From `String.compareTo` docs:

> [...] If they (Strings) have different characters at one or more index positions, 
>   let k be the smallest such index; then the string whose character at position k has the
>   smaller value, as determined by using the < operator, lexicographically
>   precedes the other string.

As ColinD suggests you will need an implementation of a `Comparator` that supports alphanumeric sorting of `Strings`. Here is an example:

```
    List<Bean> lb = new ArrayList<Bean>() {{
            add(new Bean("This is 1"));
            add(new Bean("This is 10"));
            add(new Bean("This is 11"));
            add(new Bean("This is 2"));
        }};
    final AlphaNumericComparator comparator= new AlphaNumericComparator();
    Ordering<Bean> nameOrdering = new Ordering<Bean>() {
        @Override public int compare(Bean left, Bean right) {
            return comparator.compare(left.getShape(),right.getShape());
        }
    };
    ImmutableSortedSet<Bean> sortedShapes = ImmutableSortedSet.orderedBy(nameOrdering).addAll(lb).build();
    List<Bean> orderedList = new ArrayList<>();
    orderedList.addAll(sortedShapes);
    System.out.println("orderedList:" + orderedList);
```

The `AlphaNumericComparator` (by Pierre-Luc Paour):

```
public class AlphaNumericComparator implements Comparator {
    int compareRight(String a, String b) {
        int bias = 0;
        int ia = 0;
        int ib = 0;
        for (; ; ia++, ib++) {
            char ca = charAt(a, ia);
            char cb = charAt(b, ib);
            if (!Character.isDigit(ca) && !Character.isDigit(cb))
                return bias;
            else if (!Character.isDigit(ca))
                return -1;
            else if (!Character.isDigit(cb))
                return +1;
            else if (ca < cb)
                if (bias == 0)
                    bias = -1;
                else if (ca > cb)
                    if (bias == 0)
                        bias = +1;
                    else if (ca == 0 && cb == 0)
                        return bias;
        }
    }

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        String a = o1.toString();
        String b = o2.toString();
        int ia = 0, ib = 0;
        int nza = 0, nzb = 0;
        char ca, cb;
        int result;

        while (true) {
            nza = nzb = 0;
            ca = charAt(a, ia);
            cb = charAt(b, ib);
            while (Character.isSpaceChar(ca) || ca == '0') {
                if (ca == '0')
                    nza++;
                else
                    nza = 0;
                ca = charAt(a, ++ia);
            }

            while (Character.isSpaceChar(cb) || cb == '0') {
                if (cb == '0')
                    nzb++;
                else
                    nzb = 0;
                cb = charAt(b, ++ib);
            }
            if (Character.isDigit(ca) && Character.isDigit(cb))
                if ((result = compareRight(a.substring(ia), b.substring(ib))) != 0)
                    return result;

            if (ca == 0 && cb == 0)
                return nza - nzb;
            if (ca < cb)
                return -1;
            else if (ca > cb)
                return +1;
            ++ia;
            ++ib;
        }
    }

    static char charAt(String s, int i) {
        if (i >= s.length()) {
            return 0;
        } else
            return s.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The natural ordering for `String`s in Java is lexicographical. You need to create or find a `Comparator` implementation that does what you want. If you're writing it youself you can just make a subclass of `Ordering` instead. Then you can just do:

```
Ordering<Bean> nameOrdering = myStringOrdering.onResultOf(getNameFunction);
```